# Tomcat Restart automatically Web Application on startup, after error

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, classnotfoundexception

I've a big trouble on tomcat.

Before explaine, let me tell is the first time I see something like this...

I'm building an application using JPA on Hibernate, Spring 3.0 and Jersey REST Framework.

When using glassfish, everything works fine, but deployng the same application on tomcat, I registered the following error code:

```
    GRAVE: Error deploying configuration descriptor java-zero.xml
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2527)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1010)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1483)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
        ... 34 more
```

Then tomcat restarts the application and again, the same error. In an infinite loop.

Looks like a library conflict, but I really don't have any ideas on how to solve it...

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Ciao, Davide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer suggests that you either don't have the Jersey JAR file or you've put it in the wrong place.
```

If it's the former, download it [here](http://jersey.java.net/) and add it to Tomcat.

If it's the latter, put it and all its dependencies in either your WEB-INF/lib, server/lib for Tomcat 5.x or lib for Tomcat 6.x.  (Just one, not all.)

It works with Glassfish because they've bundled it for you.  Tomcat has not.

Comment: Hi, thank's a lot for your reply!

You'll right! I found a scope clausal in my pom, I really don't remember to have putted in, that in-fact, excludes jersey-server jar at runtime. 

<pre>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope xmlns:pom="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</pre>
Thank's a lot,
Davide

Answer (score 2):

Remove all Jersey JAR from `/WEB_INF/lib` folder, refresh project and again paste all JARs of Jersey library into `/WEB_INF/lib`. Refresh project, stop server again, deploy and run.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either jersey.jar and/or jsr311-api.jar are missing from your webapp. You might check they are in the WEB-INF/lib folder.